# Magento layerd navigation error

Tags: magento

I am integrating layered navigation filter on advanced searched result page. but there is error show which are given below

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in /home/gateremo/public_html/site/app/design/frontend/gateremote/default/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml on line 36
```

I have put the code in catelog search resultpage.

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Can some one help me to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the state block. You can try below code in catalogsearch_advanced_result handle:

```html
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
<block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
</block>
```

Comment: But it couldn't show any filter option in left side

Can you please help me

Comment: I want to show like this type of filter
http://89.145.100.57/~gateremo/site/catalogsearch/result/?q=f

on this page

http://89.145.100.57/~gateremo/site/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?button_color=275

Comment: Remove the code from   <reference name="content"> and add below code under catalogsearch_result_index handle.  <reference name="left">
          <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
<block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
</block>
        </reference>

Comment: I have added your code in 
<reference name="left">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
    </block>
    </reference>

Comment: I wan to show filter option in left part of advanced search result page

Comment: Go to Catalog> Attributes> Manage Attributes> Go to repective attribute edit section and say yes to Use In Search Results Layered Navigation.

Comment: Please check this screenshot

I already do that

http://awesomescreenshot.com/05d4dsyn2b

Comment: Please check below both screenshots

    1. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d74dszv27
    2. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0df4dt0324

Comment: Hello mohitwadhawan

Can you please take a look